# How to keep regression output in a range

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to make a regression model for age estimation in `tensorflow`. My dataset consists of images for the ages from 1 to 80. I want to keep my output between these values. Basically I can do it in python as:

```
if output > 80:
    output = 80
elif output < 1:
    output = 1
```

But I can't do it in `tensorflow`. I tried:

```
one = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32)
eighty = tf.constant(80, dtype=tf.int32)

output = tf.cond(tf.less(output, one), lambda: one, lambda: output)
output = tf.cond(tf.less(eighty, output), lambda: eighty, lambda: output)
```

It throws a long error, but, I guess, this part is important:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'cond_1/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?,1], [?,1].
```

It makes sense. I am trying to compare a constant and a list(or something like list). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `tf.clip_by_value`:

```
output = tf.clip_by_value(output, clip_value_min=1, clip_value_max=80)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is so simple. I guess, using wrong words while searching costed me a couple hours.